# How to give Admins Access to move users to a Single OU

Tags: active-directory, security, permissions, users, organizational-unit

We are delegating few acceses to some admins via taskpads;
So we created a OU called "Delete" and we want the admins to move all the users to be deleted to that OU; How can we do that , how can we exclusively gives users access to move users to a single OU?

Please do let me know of any questions or clarifications.